# Laravel 10 cannot pass props to app layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following component:

**AppLayout.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class AppLayout extends Component
{
    public function __construct(
        public bool $header = false,
    ) {
    }


    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represents the component.
     */
    public function render(): View
    {
        return view('layouts.app');
    }
}
```

**views/layouts/app.blade.php**

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}" class="h-full">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta name="application-name" content="{{ config('app.name') }}">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>{{ config('app.name') }}</title>

        <style>
            [x-cloak] {
                display: none !important;
            }
        </style>

        @vite('resources/css/app.css')
        @livewireStyles
    </head>

    <body class="antialiased h-full flex flex-col">
        @if ($header)
            <header>foo</header>
        @endif

        <main class="flex-grow">{{ $slot }}</main>

        @vite('resources/js/app.js')
        @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I pass the header prop to the layout component? I tried [all](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#passing-data-to-components) suggested approaches in the docs and nothing worked.

What I want to do:

**some-page.blade.php**

```
<x-app-layout :header="true">
  ...content in a page with header...
</x-app-layout>
```

Comment: `public function __construct(public bool $header = false) { ... }` - That syntax looks... weird. Is it even valid? Shouldn't `public bool $header = false;` be _above_ that, then an argument passed to `__construct()`, like `public function __construct(bool $header) { $this->header = $header; }`? (Disclosure, I haven't worked with components in Laravel, so I could be misunderstanding)

Comment: It's valid syntax to initialize properties in the ctor in [php 8.1](https://www.amitmerchant.com/initialize-objects-right-into-the-constructor-parameters-in-php-81/)

Comment: Interesting... I'll have to poke that a bit, see how it works with arguments (since it's a little unclear from that RFC how that works). Thanks for sharing though; I honestly have never seen this syntax before 

Comment: As far as I know you'd use the `:` prefix for variables (e.g. `:header="$headerValue"`) if you are passing a constant value you drop the prefix e.g. `header="true"`. Not sure how well it works with type casting though because the value seems to be a string and I'm not sure if it automatically casts it

Comment: @apokryfos I guess that was it, I made some changes and string acts as expected